# How to animate scroll top from onclick function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation div that I want to use to navigate to different slides on my html page. I want to use the animate scrollTop to animate down to each individual id of the different slides. I wrote a function based off some stackoverflow posts I read over and a tutorial I found online and for some reason it does not work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home - Kevin Waldmann</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
    function navScroll(navId)
    {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(navId).offset().top}, 2000);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="navbar">
    <div id="navList">
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide1')">Home</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide2')">Education</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide3')">Work Experience</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide4')">Skills</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide5')">Links</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide6')">Greek Life</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide7')">Volunteering</div>
    <div class="navItem unselectable" onclick="navScroll('#slide8')">Contact</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pageContent">
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide1"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide2"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide3"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide4"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide5"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide6"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide7"></div>
        <div class="contentSpace"></div>
        <div class="contentPane" id="slide8"></div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

<

Comment: Does the console give you any errors?

Comment: I think you have to put `;` like this `onclick="navScroll('#slide8');"`

Comment: i get offset(...) is not a function. and adding the ; didn't work.

Comment: I had to change <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script> to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script> sources online say the top script should work though. I am however, developing on my local machine so do I need that http: because of that?

Comment: Yes, always when referring to a link use `http:`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
```

to

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
```